# Javascript subtraction is subtracting incorrectly

Tags: javascript

I'm making on a browser-based text game, and I'm working on combat. During testing, I'm seeing the subtraction for the weapon's damage not being subtracted properly, i.e. when I do 15 damage to the opponent and they have <10 health, the opponent is either gaining 1 hp or it's staying the same.

The player has 50 hp to begin with, and after the opponent does 13 damage, I have 32 hp left. After dealing 18 damage to the opponent (who starts with 32 hp) the opponent still has 32 hp. For clarification, the numbers are integers.

Here is my [Pen](https://codepen.io/pixelxii/pen/aaEoOx?editors=0010#0)

Is it something in my code?

Here it is:

```
Weapon.prototype.use = function(target) {
  let dmg = Math.round((Math.random() * 3) + this.damage)

  if (dmg > target.hp) {
    target.hp = 0;
  } else {
    target.hp = target.hp - dmg
    console.log(target.hp + ' ' + dmg)
  }

  if (target.hp < 0) {
    target.hp = 0
  }

  return 'You did ' + dmg + ' damage.'
}
```

EDIT:

It seems the problem is not in that function, but in Game.combat:

```
Game.combat = function(opp) {
    consul.log("c o m b a t  :: " + Player.inventory[0].use(opp))
    if(opp.hp <= 0) {
        opp.hp = 0;
        consul.error('You killed the ' + opp.name.toLowerCase())
    } else {
        consul.error('The '+ opp.name.toLowerCase() + ' has ' + opp.hp + ' health left.')
    }
    setTimeout(function() {
        consul.log("c o m b a t  :: " + opp.weapon.mUse(opp))
        if(Player.hp <= 0) {
            Player.hp = 0
            consul.log(Game.placeholder)
            consul.error('YOU DIED')
        } else {
            consul.error('You have ' + Player.hp + ' health left.')
        }
    }, Math.random()*2600+750)
}
```

Comment: please add all numbers and the wrong and right result. and add if the numbers should be integers or floats.

Comment: if you do 15dmg on an opponent with 10hp, the subtraction shouldnt execute because of the if(dmg > target.hp), so subtraction isnt the problem?

Comment: Why are you calling `parseInt` on a number?

Comment: I'm not sure why I am, that has been changed.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: are you passing in the right parameter? The player has 50 hp to begin with, and after the opponent does 13 damage shouldn't your hp be 37?

Comment: try to make a pen at [CodePen](https://www.codepen.com) containing all your application so we can interact more with your issue.

Comment: @ths Why use codepen (which so far has refused to load for 10 seconds) when you can post live snippets right here on SO?

Comment: But runnable snippets aren't modifiable.

Comment: A pen has been made and added to the question.

Comment: here Player.inventory[0].use(Player, opp) you're passing in 2 arguments, Weapon.prototype.use = function(target) this function only accepts 1, so all your doing is attack yourself.

Comment: Thank you, that was _a_ problem, but not _the_ problem here. Thanks!

Comment: you're also creating a new opponent everytime you call tutorialChamber

Comment: tutorialChamber is being called only once, when Player.location==chamber.

Comment: maybe im doing this wrong, its calling tutorialChamber everytime i type attack

Comment: No, you're doing nothing wrong. That is true, though, and so the miner's health gets reset every time...

Comment: @ChrisLi Thank you for your comment, it helped me solve the problem. I detected the first time tutorialChamber was called, and set the hp.

Comment: glad to help, gl with your game